# Missing return statement onTouch

Tags: android

```
boopSound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            boop.start();
        }

    }

});
```

Im getting an error saying "Missing return statement" I'm trying to create a button that plays a sound when it is pressed rather than when it is released which is why i'm using OnTouchListener rather than OnClickListener

Comment: onTouch returns a boolean.  You have no return.  You need to return a boolean value from that function.  And if you really need to ask this, you should actually learn Java.

Answer (score 2):

of course you should return a boolean.

The return value determines if you consumed the touch event.

In other words true means that this touch event is interesting to you and all follow up calls of this touch event like ACTION_MOVE or ACTION_UP will be delivered to you.

```
 boopSound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            boop.start();
        }

        return true; //add this line
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boopSound.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            boop.start();
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Just return `true` in order to perform that touch event. Also you could set a click listener because touch event can lead to multiple calls.